# Q: How to use plugin:find on page with multiple inline ckeditors

Tags: plugins, find, ckeditor

A while ago I made a "Story/Novel editor" that I tested with various editors, unfortunately all of the editors crashed mobile web browsers when they grew too big.  My solution was to use multiple inline editors, one for every paragraph (that activates when it's clicked on or by the keyboard) in CKEditor 4.5.5

Like https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/#inline

One problem that I could never solve was the find plugin.  It only searches the current paragraph, so you'd have to use the browser's find instead.

On a page like https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/#inline Is there a way to get the find plugin to search in all 5 editors on the page?

I checked the commit history of the plugin and it doesn't seem like it's changed much in 2 years.

Comment: Maybe add the link to the plugin for clarity: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/find

Comment: I think there is no easy way. As in a configureable options way. You have to dig in the code: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/master/plugins/find/dialogs/find.js and change it to account for multiple CKEditors.